# Revolution slider transitions

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hello I have a problem with the revolution slider anytime I set the video slider to auto play on each slide it wont transition to the next one.
 But it if switch it off its fine,but it means you cant play the videos can anyone please help me.

Thank you

Michael

Answer (score 0):

If your video is an html5 in video settings just make sure you have enable this option Next Slide On End[x], that will tell the plugin to play the next slide show when the video ends.